# call command line program with php

Tags: php, command-line

I have a program running on my command line. The program allows one to type in a username and returns a bunch of information pertaining to that user. I assume it is possible to access this program from php, and even store the information in a variable. Anyone know *how* to do this though?

Thanks in advance for the advice

Comment: have you entered your question in google? It gives you answers!

Comment: @Topener I obviously have. It is difficult to know which answer is correct because I am not entirely sure what I am looking for. I found getopt() but it is not working (probably because I am not using it correctly)

Comment: +1 -- question is acceptable, needs some affirmation :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) should help you. A quick example:

```
<?php
  $out = array();
  exec = ('ls /ver 2>&1', $out);
  print_r($out);
?>
```

Comment: Awesome, I found the example quite helpful. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

try using the `system()` command.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

or `exec()`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: One more thing... when I try something like exec("whoami"), I get the result www-data. Do you know why this is :S?

Comment: That will be the user that the webserver is running as.

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation for [system()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) and [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), it should what you need.